# In mysql, is there any way to use a field value as an argument when using cast as decimal?

Tags: mysql

Given a table with 2 fields `number_value` and `decimal_value` I would like to be able to pass the decimal_value as an argument when casting.

Let say the string in number_value is "219578684607.829" and decimal_value is "2".

This works:

```
SELECT CAST("219578684607.829" AS DECIMAL(25,2));
```

This does not:

```
SELECT CAST("219578684607.829" AS DECIMAL(25,CAST("2" AS UNSIGNED)));
```

Ultimately, the query I'm trying to make work looks like this:

```
Select cast(number_value as DECIMAL(25, decimal_value));
```

The table has thousands of rows with different values. I dont understand why this is not possible and can think of many different situations where I'd want it to be.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you want? If you want to round your values to different precisions using rounding rules which are implemented in CAST() function then this is possible. If you want to obtain the values with different datatype (and according precision) in the same column then this is absolutely impossible. Because the column values will be converted to one, the most common, datatype - i.e. DECIMAL with maximal precision over the whole column (which may result in overflow even).

Comment: I want to get the number_value with the corresponding decimal_value precision.  I deduced it is not possible using cast, but maybe there is another way to achieve even if it is only superficially as a string?

Comment: The second argument to `DECIMAL(N, M)` is the scale, not the precision. Besides, you can't make the scale _or_ the precision different per row in the same column of the same result set.

Comment: Right sorry for the confusion.  I can get variable  scale or precision but I have to roll my own with string manipulation via decimal_value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to understand why it is not possible if you look at the SQL parser code. The syntax rule for `precision` does not accept expressions. It only accepts unsigned integer literals.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L7361-L7367

```
precision:
          '(' NUM ',' NUM ')'
          {
            $$.length= $2.str;
            $$.dec= $4.str;
          }
        ;
```

This is what the ANSI/ISO SQL standard defines for the syntax. Precision and scale may only be unsigned integers.

You can't use an expression there. If you need the scale to be variable, you must use dynamic SQL.

You also said:

> The table has thousands of rows with different values.

Even if you use dynamic SQL, you can't make a numeric column have a different scale on each row. In SQL, a given column must have the same data type on every row of a result set.

Comment: You're right, it is easy to understand that it cant be done because the standard doesn't allow it.  Is there a standard work around for this example?  Just use varchar and string methods?

Comment: I still can't tell what you're trying to do by making the scale of a decimal vary per row. You must have the same precision and scale on every row of the result set in a given column. Can you edit your question above and show an example of a few rows of data and the query result set you want to produce?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... the answer is to not use cast, but to use string functions like LENGTH, REPLACE, INSERT, etc which allow expressions in which you can use the corresponding decimal_value to manipulate number_value.